# ESP32 not updating the variable when multiple cores are used

Tags: c++, esp32, freertos

My plan is to collect data from ESP32's `CORE-1` and use ESP32's `CORE-0` for all other tasks. However, I see that the variables are not updated properly when multiple cores are used. Here in this example, I see that the value of `getAllData` is updated only once.

```cpp
const TickType_t xDelay = 1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS;

TaskHandle_t collectData;


bool volatile getAllData;
bool volatile dataReadyToSend;





void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("setup() is running on core ");
  Serial.println(xPortGetCoreID());
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(collectDataCode,"collectData",10000,NULL,1,&collectData,0);
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    Serial.flush();
    getAllData = true;
  }
  Serial.print("From loop: ");
  Serial.println(getAllData);
  if (dataReadyToSend) {
    dataReadyToSend = false;
  }
  delay(1000);
}



void collectDataCode(void * params) {
  while (1) {
    Serial.print("From collectData: ");
    Serial.println(getAllData);
    if (getAllData) {
      getAllData=0;
    }
    vTaskDelay( xDelay );
  }  
}
```

Output of the above code is given below. Where I typed `xxx`. It is observed that the variable `getAllData` got updated at this instance, but not changing later.

```
From collectData: 0
From loop: 0
From collectData: 0
From loop: 0
From collectData: 0
From loop: 0
From collectData: 0
From loop: 0
From collectData: 0
xxx
From loop: 1
From collectData: 1
From loop: 1
From collectData: 1
From loop: 1
From collectData: 1
From loop: 1
From collectData: 1
```

**UPDATE**

Upon suggestions, I used `atomic` with the following code. Still I see no success.

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;
#else
#include <stdatomic.h>
#endif



TaskHandle_t collectData;



atomic<bool> getAllData;
atomic<bool> dataReadyToSend;


#include "collectData.h"




void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("setup() is running on core ");
  Serial.println(xPortGetCoreID());
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(collectDataCode,"collectData",10000,NULL,1,&collectData,0);
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    Serial.flush();
    atomic_store (&getAllData, true);
  }
  Serial.print("From loop: ");
  Serial.println(atomic_load(&getAllData));
  if (dataReadyToSend) {
    dataReadyToSend = false;
  }
  delay(1000);
}



void collectDataCode(void * params) {
  while (1) {
    Serial.print("From collectData: ");
    Serial.println(atomic_load(&getAllData));
    if (atomic_load(&getAllData)) {
      atomic_store (&getAllData, false);
    }
    vTaskDelay( xDelay );
  }
  
  
}
```

Comment: `volatile` doesn't do anything for cross-thread synchronization. Use [`std::atomic<bool>`.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

Comment: @PeteBecker, I see no success with `atomic`. I updated the question with the `atomic` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem is not with the variable itself, it is with the Arduino's `Serial.flush()`. From the version 1.0, arduino is using `Serial.flush()` to clear the outgoing serial data not the incoming serial data. So, I replaced the `Serial.flush()` with the following code.

```cpp
while(Serial.available()) {
  Serial.read();
}
```

With this update, my code is working good. Thanks to the comment of @PeteBecker, I am using atomic. The final code and results are given below.

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;
#else
#include <stdatomic.h>
#endif



TaskHandle_t collectData;



atomic<bool> getAllData;
atomic<bool> dataReadyToSend;


#include "collectData.h"




void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("setup() is running on core ");
  Serial.println(xPortGetCoreID());
  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(collectDataCode,"collectData",10000,NULL,1,&collectData,0);
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    while(Serial.available()) {
      Serial.read();
    }
    getAllData.store(true);
    Serial.println("Received data request");
  }
  Serial.print("From loop: ");
  Serial.println(getAllData.load());
  if (dataReadyToSend) {
    dataReadyToSend = false;
  }
  delay(1000);
}



void collectDataCode(void * params) {
  while (1) {
    Serial.print("From collectData: ");
    Serial.println(atomic_load(&getAllData));
    if (getAllData.load()) {
      getAllData.store(false);
    }
    vTaskDelay( xDelay );
  }
  
  
}
```

Results

```
From loop: 0
From collectData: 0
From loop: 0
From collectData: 0
From loop: 0
From collectData: 0
.
From loop: 0
From collectData: 0
Received data request
From loop: 1
From collectData: 1
From loop: 0
From collectData: 0
From loop: 0
From collectData: 0
From loop: 0
From collectData: 0
From loop: 0
From collectData: 0
From loop: 0
```

Comment: "For some reason, the Serial.flush() is not clearing the Serial.available()" Because `flush()` flushes the **outgoing** data, and `available()` returns the size of **incoming** data.

Comment: @gre_gor, I misunderstood it. Seems very silly. I am sorry to waste time for everyone.

Comment: @gre_gor, you contributed more than what I did. If you post the answer, I will select as the accepted answer.

Comment: You can just edit yours to clarify the misunderstanding.